# Is multilingual cross-posting allowed in SO sites?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting, portuguese-stack-overflow

I’ve seen SO in Portuguese, Japanese, and Russian languages, particularly the Russian SO site is showing a lot of traffic.

Since search engines don’t do multilingual searches, at least not yet, maybe making multilingual cross-posts cold help one to get a useful response as quickly as possible, which is basically what the SE sites are for.

I’m not asking whether you agree or not with multilingual cross-posting but only if it’s allowed, so please keep it in mind to the moment of down voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone with a reasonably good command of written English would be better off just posting on the main Stack Overflow site simply because you have a much wider audience than on the language specific sites.

However, if your English isn't that great then posting just on the appropriate language site would be the best choice. There you'll get the answer explained in *your* language rather than having to translate to and from English which may well result in more confusion.

If your native language is not currently supported then go to Area 51 and find (or start) the proposal and support that. Perhaps even approach Stack Exchange about being the Community Manager for your language - that's one of the big things that holds up the launch of a language specific site.

Comment: I see, it is allowed although not recommended, since it would cause a lot more trouble, at least it you have to use a translator.